# Given some $v,k$ how many functions exist that satisfy the constraints $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx = v$ and $f(a) = k$?

Tags: calculus

Some arbitrary constants $v$ and $k$ are given. Let a function $f(x)$ be *valid* if:

$\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx  = v$ and $f(a) = k$ (for some arbitrary $a$)

I am interested to know how many such valid functions exist. One of them is obvious, where $f(x) = \frac{k^2}{2v}x$

Intuitively, it appears to me that there are more, but I am  not sure.

Comment: $2^{\aleph_{0}}$ many, no mater whether you are considering Lebesgue or
Riemann integral.

Comment: Sorry, I should say $2^{2^{\aleph_{0}}}$ .

Comment: I’m sorry, what does that stylised N represent? And what is the difference between Riemann and Lebesgue integral? I only know high-school calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generalize your example. The function $f(x) = \dfrac{k^{n+1}x^n}{(n+1)^nv^n}$ is valid with $a = \dfrac{(n+1)v}{k}$ for every non-negative integer $n$.

Also, for any non-zero real number $c$, the function $f(x) = \begin{cases}c & \text{if} \ x \neq \tfrac{v}{c} \\ k & \text{if} \ x = \tfrac{v}{c}\end{cases}$ is valid with $a = \tfrac{v}{c}$.

Of course, there are even more examples than this.

Comment: Might I ask how you found that function?

Comment: I set $f(x) = Cx^n$ and used the constraints $\int_0^af(x)\,dx = v$ and $f(a) = k$ to solve for $C$ and $a$.

Comment: Ah I see it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=e^{\alpha x}$ for $\alpha=\frac{{k-1}}{{v}}$ and $a = \frac{{v\ln (k)}}{{k - 1}}$. I think you can consider functions that their derivatives generate themselves.

Comment: You can try $f(x)=\alpha\tan(bx)$ as well.

Comment: This is nice. :D